# Is there a way to vary the font size in print statement of python-3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, fonts

I am building a simple python application without GUI, in which I wished to add some colors, which I was able to do with the help of some modules like termcolor, tqdm, simple_colors etc.. **I also need a way to increase font size in the print statement whenever necessary**. It would be good if someone also can tell me if there is a way to **use different font styles** at required positions rather than changing the font of the entire application.